# Adding Git and copying files from EC2

Tags: git, amazon-ec2

I have an EC2 instance where I installed a software using yum and then changed some config files in the software directories.

I want to copy these directories to my local computer and also be able to run git diff and see what changes I made to the config files (I made these changes months ago so I don't remember).

Is this possible and what would you recommend? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

From what I understand, you are asking to use `git diff` when git wasn't initialized before. This is simply not possible as git doesn't show any changes made before it.

Howsoever, there are methods to recover old file changes. Try reading this article - [can overwritten files be recovered](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/150423)

As for the second part of the question. You can copy these files to your local system easily using `scp`.

```
scp -i /directory/to/abc.pem user@ec2-xx-xx-xxx-xxx.compute-1.amazonaws.com:path/to/file /your/local/directory/files/to/download
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you are describing provisioning of your server - installing new software and keeping track of config files changes sounds pretty much as something [Ansible](https://www.ansible.com/resources/videos/quick-start-video) could do.

This is a relatively small investment to get used to (especially with Ansible) but you will feel the advantages right away.

To answer your particular questions - while running Ansible even after some manual changes, it will show you differences in the config files you have made. So it will be up to you either to revert them, or adjust ansible files.

Ansible configuration can be stored in git, so you have all advantages of version control to look at the history of changes you made.